# How to retrive list of subscribers from my own youtube channel using C# Asp.net.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-data-api

I want this code to be modified for retrieving subscribers name or ids

```
YouTubeService yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {     ApiKey = "MY API KEY" });
var searchListRequest = yt.Search.List("snippet");
searchListRequest.ChannelId = "MY CHANNEL ID";
var searchListResult = searchListRequest.Execute();
foreach (var item in searchListResult.Items)
{
         //retrive each subscribers name or id  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com! Have you tried to find out how to do that? If yes what is the problem with your code? If now try to find the guide of the youtube's API first. I am sure Youtube's API has guide describing a lot of cases how to use it in different situations.

Comment: yes i tried to use the java script method provided by google https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps.but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) with `part` containing `subscriberSnippet` and `mySubscribers=true` is the solution to your problem.